# Spring Boot 2.3 build image failed

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven

I updated [my sample](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample) to Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE, and tried to build the image from `spring-boot:build-image` goal directly, but failed.

My work env for this sample.

- Windows 10 and the latest Docker Desktop
- Java 11(AdoptOpenJDK 11)

```sh
# docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:23:10 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:29:16 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683

#java -version
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.6+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.6+10, mixed mode)
```

When I ran the command in the project root folder.

```sh
mvn clean spring-boot:build-image -DskipTests
```

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image (default-cli) on project angular-spring-reactive-sample-server: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image failed: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=gcr.io%2Fpaketo-buildpacks%2Fbuilder%3Abase-platform-api-0.3' failed with status code 500 "Internal Server Error" ->
```

I have tried to set a `HTTP_PROXY` env before running this command, failed.

Add `-e` to the command and got the log like this.

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image (default-cli) @ angular-spring-reactive-sample-server ---
[INFO] Building image 'docker.io/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample-server:lastest'
[INFO]
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/builder:base-platform-api-0.3' 100%
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  30.757 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-17T16:38:02+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image (default-cli) on project angular-spring-reactive-sample-server: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image failed: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=gcr.io%2Fpaketo-buildpacks%2Fbuilder%3Abase-platform-api-0.3' failed with status code 500 "Internal Server Error" -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image (default-cli) on project angular-spring-reactive-sample-server: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image failed: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=gcr.io%2Fpaketo-buildpacks%2Fbuilder%3Abase-platform-api-0.3' failed with status code 500 "Internal Server Error"
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image failed: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=gcr.io%2Fpaketo-buildpacks%2Fbuilder%3Abase-platform-api-0.3' failed with status code 500 "Internal Server Error"
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.DockerEngineException: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=gcr.io%2Fpaketo-buildpacks%2Fbuilder%3Abase-platform-api-0.3' failed with status code 500 "Internal Server Error"
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.HttpClientTransport.execute (HttpClientTransport.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.HttpClientTransport.post (HttpClientTransport.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.DockerApi$ImageApi.pull (DockerApi.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Builder.pullBuilder (Builder.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Builder.build (Builder.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.BuildImageMojo.buildImage (BuildImageMojo.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.BuildImageMojo.execute (BuildImageMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Comment: Log: `Successfully built image 'docker.io/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample-server:lastest'` and `docker images` command gives info regarding image as name as previous size: 270MB, CREATED: 40 years ago

Comment: works for me, able to build image successfully, executed command `mvn clean -DskipTests=true spring-boot:build-image at angular-spring-reactive-sample-master/server`

Comment: @dkb I was thinking this could be a network problem in China, there are a lot of similar issues in before experince, but I am not sure. And it reports **Server error** for *localhost/v1.24/images/create*, I am also confused if this is my local Docker related, I added my docker info in the original question.

Comment: Docker should log something if image creation fails with a server error. I'm not sure where the logs are on Windows, but I think it would be worth checking them. Hopefully they'll contain something that helps to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I added logging with `-e` option. Currently, the Spring boot maven plugin uses the fixed **1.24** version of Docker API, but Docker 19.03 uses 1.40, not sure if they are compatible.

Comment: @Hantsy Maven's the client here and, as it's a server error, it's the logging from the Docker side that's interesting. You can use `docker version` to see the minimum API version. For 1.40 in 19.03 it should be 1.12.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson It failed at `DockerApi$ImageApi.pull`, I have not explored the related codes, but I also used `testcontainers` in projects which used Docker Java API to pull down docker images and worked well. Is there some specific operations in **buildpack** docker pull here?

Comment: @Hantsy Comments on a question aren't a good place for a discussion. I'm happy to try and help you, but to do so I'll need the information that I have asked for, namely the logs from your Docker host so that we can see why it responded with a 500.

Comment: @Hantsy: The image is being tagged with version 'lastest'. Was it intentional or you meant 'latest'? I don't think that's the issue here though.

Comment: @CoderPraBhu Yeah, it is typo error,I have fixed it in my codes some days ago. This is a China specific network problem. I've confirmed it works on Github actions.

Comment: Okay. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Steps to use spring boot 2.3 to build image in Ubuntu & in China:

- First check docker is properly installed (by running `sudo apt install docker.io`, add current user into docker group)
- download lantern from github
- start lantern in terminal by typing `lantern &`
- from start.spring.io, choose gradle, spring boot 2.3, webflux or anything you need and download the zip
- unzip the file
- open lantern in browser (I use chrome), from settings to check the proxy info
- add the proxy into gradle-wrapper.properties under `$project/gradle/wrapper`

  systemProp.proxySet=true
  systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
  systemProp.https.proxyPort=45587
  systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
  systemProp.http.proxyPort=45587
- `sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/docker.service` and add following line in `[service]` section:

  EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/docker
- edit the `/etc/default/docker` file with settings in lantern:

  ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:37267
- `docker pull gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/builder:base-platform-api-0.3`
- `docker pull gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/run:base-cnb`
- Then, it should be working by `./gradlew bootBuildImage`

When lantern is not stable, retry docker pull or gradlew, it could resume/retry the download...

When github is blocked, add following into build.gradle, assuming 172.17.0.1 is the ip of docker0 interface:

```
bootBuildImage {
    environment = [
        "HTTP_PROXY" : "http://172.17.0.1:45587",
        "http_proxy" : "http://172.17.0.1:45587",
        "HTTPS_PROXY": "http://172.17.0.1:45587",
        "https_proxy": "http://172.17.0.1:45587"                
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hello,i followed your comments, i use maven thou.But i am getting the below error.  Can you help me which this maven project.

Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 7

Comment: I didn't try mvnw. [creator] would download the jre from github. Better add following into build.gradle:

bootBuildImage {
    environment = [
            "ALL_PROXY" : "socks5://localhost:45587"
    ]
}

Comment: This should be a specific problem in China, I have configured a Github actions to build docker images it works.

Comment: @CaiMao Under linux, docker working is a little different from Windows, there is no vm to run dockerd, docker client and dockerd communicates via sock directly. But under Windows, docker is running in Hyper-VM, the docker client connects to docked  via a network protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Have the some problem. But it is solved after I switch to spring-boot-starter-parent 2.4.1

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.1</version>
   <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```